# Is there any problem to run on Windows a NodeJS application that was built on a Linux?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Here's my sceario:

I have an NodeJS application that connects to a PostgreSQL database, make use of a lot of Azure libs for Storage Account, WebPubSub, DataFactory... it's hosted on a Windows server.

My current pipeline process builds this application, then copies the node_modules from the install process into the dist folder, along with other files, then package it. So, the target host doesn't need to run `npm install` again. Currently this all happens on a Windows Agent.

But now, I need to implement a self-hosted agent with Ubuntu. So, supposing the process keeps the same, will I have any problems if I ship the node_modules from the Linux agent to a Windows host?

I've searched on the web but couldn't find anything about running a "cross" built application. I'm worried about the binary libraries, like the PG. Isn't it going to have problems when I download it on a Linux, but host it on a Windows?

Example:
Create a project on a Linux machine, with pg library. Run `npm i` on this project, then copy the project, including node_modules, and paste it on a Windows. Will this face problems to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short is yes, you will have issues.

Long answer is...maybe. There are a few things I can quickly think off the top of my head that's relevant when running Node apps on different architectures/OSs (and I'm sure there are more):

- binary Node modules built for a specific OS/Node version
- passing environment variables in npm scripts, wrapped in double quotes etc
- path separators (backslash on Windows vs forward slash on Linux)
- path case sensitivity (case sensitive on Linux).

Your issue is the first one: moving the node_modules folder between Windows and Linux. This *might* work if you don't have any binaries and just modules that are `required` in Node. However if you *do* have binaries, then as you rightly point out they'll fail if they were built for one architecture and you try to run them on another.

A real-world example: the old Node Sass package (before Dart Sass) was copiled into a binary. If you swap environment you'd see errors like:

> Error: Missing binding C:...\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node. Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 14.x

### How to fix

You've got a few ways to get round this:

- build and host on the same OS
- build on Linux and host in Linux in a container (e.g. docker) on Windows via WSL, if you have permissions
- run `npm rebuild` after deploying onto the Windows box.

The `npm rebuild` (or the `npm rb` alias) rebuilds binaries, useful for after you've changed Node version or, as in your case, operating system.

### An additional recommendation

I'd recommend double checking your dependencies are correctly installed as either *devDependencies* when required at build time and *dependencies* if required at runtime (or both build and run time). You can then run your build commands on linux to generate your website/artifacts, and then run `npm prune --production` to strip out the *devDependencies*. This means your package will just include the runtime *dependencies*.

In my experience the runtime dependencies will likely *not* be binaries and you won't have your original issue, and a smaller bundle size.

Comment: Thank you very much! You taught an entire class! I decided to split my pipeline agents in two: one specific for Linux hosts, and another for Windows specific hosts. This way, I save my time that I would have to spend trying to find out what is "probably" going wrong when an app is deployed in this "cross" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you mention would have issues, yes.

Depending on what you use to build/package your executable, you can sometimes pass a platform argument

i.e.
for `pkg` you would tell it `pkg -t node16-win-x64 index.js` or 'pkg -t node16-linux-x64`

This way, the packager will make sure everything is cross-compiled, downloaded for the right platform...

Comment: Thanks, @JerkoNikolic. During this time, I also made a test using only the pg library and no problem was found. But, what you said is true: I don't know, and I can't know, if any of my libraries will cause a problem. I'll make more tests.